# A result on Lie group actions on 15-dimensional spheres?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, group-actions

In this [interview by Eric Weinstein to Roger Penrose, Timestamp 1:24:05.](https://youtu.be/mg93Dm-vYc8?t=5045), what result is the host talking about?

Transcription of the relevant part:

> "If you have two sets of symmetries, known as Lie groups, that act transitively on the same sphere in usual position, then either their intersection acts transitively on that sphere, or the dimension of that sphere is $15$. And I believe the intersection of the groups looks like the electro-strong group. So it's very close to the... particle spectrum of theoretical physics... pulled out of nowhere just by talking about sphere transitive group actions"

Edit: it seems like the host is trying to recall a particular result. Given how bizarre and peculiar the result seems to be (in line with dimension $4$ being special for differentiable structures on Euclidean spaces, or dimension $7$ in the case of exotic spheres), I would like to know if it's a real thing and, in case it's real, what's the exact statement.

In particular,

1. I don't care if the exact quoted statement is true or false;
2. I only want to know if there's a result that sounds very similar to that one and is actually true and, if you're aware of such a result, what's its exact statement.

Comment: Maybe you could transcribe the relevant bit for people's convenience?

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: done.

Comment: It reads kinda like nonsense (but maybe is a paraphrase of a real result). For starters: how can we "intersect" two different Lie groups?

Comment: @SamHopkins, maybe intersecting their images in $\operatorname{Diff}(S^n)$?

Comment: Very obviously, my question is about tracing the real result of which that quote is probably a paraphrase. I find it difficult to believe that such a combination of images (we have Lie groups acting on shperes, and only dimension $15$ satisfies a general property) could stick in the head of a quite mathematically educated person if there was no real result out there.

Comment: Well, the statement as quoted is clearly false:  For example, consider the group $G$ of left multiplications by unit quaternions, which acts transitively on the $3$-sphere (i.e., the unit quaternions), and the group $H$ of right multiplications by unit quaternions, which also acts transitively on the $3$-sphere.  Their intersection is $\{\pm I\}$, which does not act transitively on the $3$-sphere.  Something similar works for every odd-dimensional sphere, not just $S^{15}$.

Comment: I won't edit it out because it's there intentionally, but I think that the question would be better without the last paragraph.  If you won't trust people to reply in good faith, then I think that this question doesn't belong on MO.  (I don't think clarifying comments, even free-wheeling ones, count as "pretend[ing] not to understand what I'm asking".)

Comment: @LSpice: you're absolutely right. Deleted.

Comment: Maybe the "in usual position" part is supposed to mean that the two subgroups of $\mathrm{Diff}(S^n)$ are "in general position" inside of $\mathrm{Diff}(S^n)$, e.g., we conjugate them by a random element? And maybe this defeats Robert Bryant's counterexample?

Comment: Has anyone tried contacting the person who said this?

Comment: @DeaneYang: But Penrose confirmed his words!

Comment: If I had to guess, he was alluding to some property of octonions such as the existence of the octonionic projective plane and nonexistence of higher dimensional octonionic projective spaces. The dimension does not quite match though (16, not 15).

Comment: @C.F.G, who's asserting this? Penrose or Weinstein? On the video (I jumped to where these words were said), it was Weinstein.

Comment: @C. F. G.: maybe Penrose was just politely nodding even though he didn't know what Weinstein was talking about, who knows...

Comment: His name is Eric Weinstein. Is he related to Alan Weinstein?

Comment: @DeaneYang I asked him and gave him a link to this question.

Comment: @VítTuček: thanks. So, maybe we'll see if Robert Bryant's answer is what he was trying to recall. At this point I think it's likely.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My guess is that Weinstein was thinking of this fact, but didn't get it out correctly:

For every $n\not=15$, there is a compact Lie group $H_n\subseteq\mathrm{SO}(n{+}1)$ that acts transitively on the $n$-sphere such that any Lie group $G$ that acts transitively and effectively on the $n$-sphere contains a subgroup $G'$ that acts transitively on the $n$-sphere and is conjugate to $H_n$ in $\mathrm{Diff}(S^n)$.

There are two non-isomorphic subgroups, $\mathrm{Spin}(9)$ and $\mathrm{Sp}(4)$ of $\mathrm{SO}(16)$, both of dimension $36$, that act transitively on $S^{15}$ such that any Lie group $G$ that acts transitively on $S^{15}$ contains a subgroup  $G'$ that is conjugate to (exactly) one of these two subgroups in $\mathrm{Diff}(S^{15})$.

Note:

$\bullet$ For $m\not=0,3$, $H_{2m}\simeq \mathrm{SO}(2m{+}1)$,
while $H_0\simeq\mathrm{O}(1)$ and $H_6 \simeq \mathrm{G}_2$,

$\bullet$ for $m\not=0$, $H_{4m+1}\simeq \mathrm{SU}(2m{+}1)$ while $H_1\simeq\mathrm{SO}(2)$, and

$\bullet$ for $m\not=4$, $H_{4m-1}\simeq\mathrm{Sp}(m)$.

This follows from Borel's classification of the Lie groups acting transitively on spheres.

**N.B.:**  The phrase 'and effectively' in the above statement is needed to rule out the following kinds of (ineffective) actions:   First, $\mathbb{Z}$ has a transitive action on $S^0 = \{-1,1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ but has no subgroup isomorphic to $\mathrm{O}(1)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$. Second, the simply-connected cover of $H_1=\mathrm{SO}(2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, and it acts transitively on $S^1$ without containing a subgroup isomorphic to $H_1 = \mathrm{SO}(2)$.  Third, for $m\not=0,3$, $H_{2m}\simeq\mathrm{SO}(2m{+}1)$ has a nontrivial double cover $\mathrm{Spin}(2m{+}1)$ that acts transitively on $S^{2m}$ but does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $H_{2m}$.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer I was looking for. (In fact, if  "even Robert Bryant didn't know about such a result", I would've had a good reason to suspect that it didn't actually exist :)  )

Comment: @Qfwfq:  You're welcome.  It took a while to figure out what he was referencing, but given that the conversation was at a level in which "you can do calculus in different ways only in dimension $4$" is meant to convey "only $\mathbb{R}^4$ supports non-diffeomorphic smooth structures", it's not too outrageous. The key was realizing what he was trying to convey with the phrase "in the usual position"; indeed, with the *usual* tabulation of the transitive subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(n{+}1)$, they do all contain $H_n$, except for $n=15$. What the(?) "electro-strong group" is, though, I have no idea.

Comment: @RobertBryant What is the intersection of $Spin(9)$ and $Sp(4)$?

Comment: Presumably he means $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ by the electro-strong group, governing the Standard Model. Is this is $Spin(9) \cap Sp(4)$, appropriately conjugated inside $SO(16)$?

Comment: @IanAgol: Well, each group does contain a subgroup with the right Lie algebra (which is often enough for physicists), but the two subgroups are not conjugate in $\mathrm{SO}(16)$. Maybe there are less obvious subgroups that are conjugate, but I don't see it. Meanwhile, each group also contains a copy of $\mathrm{SU}(4)$ as a subgroup and those two subgroups *are* conjugate in $\mathrm{SO}(16)$, so the electro-strong group is not the maximal possible dimension of an intersection of conjugates of the two groups in $\mathrm{SO}(16)$. The minimal intersection is the common center $\{\pm I_{16}\}$.

Comment: @IanAgol: Update. I realized (duh) that because the electro-strong group has rank 4, a maximal torus for it would also be a maximal torus in the two larger groups, so everything reduces to roots and weights. By this, it's easy to see that each of $\mathrm{Spin}(9)$ and $\mathrm{Sp}(4)$ has a connected subgroup with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{u}(1)$ and that it is unique up to conjugacy. However, as noted above, these two subgroups are not conjugate in $\mathrm{SO}(16)$, so no conjugates of the two groups can have the electro-strong group as intersection.

Comment: @RobertBryant okay, then he probably meant something else by the electrostrong group.

Comment: Googling "electrostrong" I found this [https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-016-4568-9] and this [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09367.pdf], in which a search for "electrostrong" in the page includes the sentences "...invariant under the electrostrong $SU(4)$ symmetry group" and "...spontaneous symmetry breaking of $SU(2)\times SU(3)$ to an electrostrong $SU(3)$", respectively. I have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: @Qfwfq:  More and more, I'm begining to think that 'electrostrong' is a name applied to a sequence of groups rather than a single group.  As I remarked above, one can 'position' (i.e., conjugate) $\mathrm{Spin}(9)$ and $\mathrm{Sp}(4)$ in $\mathrm{SO}(16)$ so that their intersection is $\mathrm{SU}(4)$, and, maybe, this is what Weinstein had in mind.

Comment: It seems odd that he acts like it's "out of nowhere" that the group SU(4) would show up "just" by talking about sphere transitive group actions. If anything, the magic is that the very basic Lie group SU(4) has this deep connection to the "electro-strong force" and the "particle spectrum" etc

Comment: Off topic: @RobertBryant: Happy 67th birthday!

Comment: Off topic: @C.F.G:  Thanks!

Comment: In the standard model, the gauge group of the strong force is $SU(3)$ and the gauge group of electromagnetism is a $U(1)$ subgroup of electroweak $SU(2)$ x $U(1)$, so electro-strong would mean $SU(3)$ x $U(1)$.